# Looping through Magento attribute values skips the first item

Tags: magento, loops, attributes, foreach

This is an ajax file running the following code:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); //getting product model
    foreach ($violins as $k => $v)
       {
           $_product = $model->load($v); //getting product object for particular product id
           $violinmodel = $_product->getAttributeText('Violinmodel'); //grabbing the violinmodel attribute value
           echo $violinmodel;
       }
```

$violin contains an array with three product ID's. My output is echoing the attribute value for the second and third ID's fine, but is NOT echoing the first ID!

I don't get this at all! Why would it completely skip the first ID in the loop and not echo anything, while echoing the following ID's without a problem?

The attributes are set up properly and no matter how I rearrange the ID's in the $violins array, the first attribute value is always skipped. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializing `$model` outside of your loop is unsafe. You might think that you are being more efficient with memory and/or function calls but you're asking for trouble. The `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` object is being loaded at that time, and calling `->load()` isn't giving you a new object, it's just setting the data of your existing one. Except, you'll get strange behavior when not all of the data gets overwritten (for example if ProductA has a Violinmodel attribute and ProductB doesn't... it will look like ProductA.Violinmodel == ProductB.Violinmodel). For that reason, you should always put your model inside your loop.

```
foreach ($violins as $k => $v) {
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($v); //getting product
    if ($_product->getId() == $v) { // sanity check
        $violinmodel = $_product->getAttributeText('Violinmodel'); //grabbing the violinmodel attribute value
        echo $violinmodel;
    }
}
```

Or, as benmarks suggested, load this data via a collection:

```
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('Violinmodel')
    ->addIdFilter($violins);
foreach ($_products as $_product) {
    echo $_product->getAttributeText('Violinmodel'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate over a product collection in Magento, the items it contains are actually product object instances. What you are doing here (hitting the database multiple times, loading all attribute) is unnecessary given what you are trying to accomplish (getting one attribute). Try adding the attribute to the collection to begin with and iterate over it:

```
$coll = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                                           ->addAttributeToSelect('Violinmodel');
                                           //be certain that the attribute code is capitalized...

foreach ($coll as $product) {
    //var_dump($product->debug()); //for example
    var_dump($product->getAttributeText('Violinmodel));
}
```